# Changing the vertical alignment of floated elements

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I am working on developing a mobile version of an events page that uses divs for columns and floats for formatting. I want to alternate the sides of the event posters when on a desktop layout but as it is now, when the floats stack vertically, the event posters end up AFTER the description of the events. I have been inside the CSS and the inspector forever now and can't seem to make it work. I tried switching the floats from left to right, adding clear:both and clear:left/right and messed with the min- and max-width and column percentages to no avail. The link to the page on the beta site is here: http://oxford.beta.st/events/.

I feel like there should be a simple solution... Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be working good for me, the poster ends up centered above the title and the description... Am I not very clear on the issue here?

Comment: It looks like the problem happens only when your window is 850px wide or less. As I understand it, you want the posters to always be shown above the description then, not alternating being shown above and below the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I notice you are using `.column1` and `.column2` and you are alternating to use one time for the description and one time for the poster. So it's behaving as it should by adding your "even" poster at the bottom where the description should be.

This means that the poster markup ends up lower than it should be, in this case I would suggest a different approach with CSS `:nth-child` [pseudo selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) so your markup remains the same (meaning always use `.column1` for the poster) but you can use CSS to style and float depending on the element.

Another great resource full of examples on how to use this powerful pseudo selector is [found here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

**Edited:**

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/ATnUt/)

Added this fiddle in order to show how to use the nth-child for this specific issue. Please notice how I'm saying, every row do this for `.column1` and for `.column2`

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need but after adding this:

.two_columns_25_75>.column1:nth-child(even) {
float: right!important;
}

to the CSS, I don't see any change, even in the inspector. Not sure what I'm doing wrong... my first time using nth-child so I'm sure I'm missing something

Comment: I also switched around the column layout so all the posters are in .column1 and all the descriptions are in .column2

Comment: the `:nth-child` pseudo selector can get pretty tricky at first, but once you understand things such as the fact that the index starts at zero, that you can use "even or odd" nth selectors, and so on. The thing to look to do here is to use `:nth-child(even)` so when the `.column1` selector us an "even" number it has certain CSS styles (these would be a float to the opposite side and different margins and paddings to accomodate) So this way you keep the markup the same for all and the CSS handles setting it to one side and the other.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @sulfureous. Now I have the pseudo selector in there working but for some reason it is applying to all the .column1 elements and not just the odd ones (even though I'm seeing the nth-child selector in the source). I'm losing my mind.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm setting up a fiddle that you can implement in just a couple of minutes.

Comment: I added the edit to my answer by providing a fiddle with the nth-child odd example that you couldn't get to work. I think the issue is that you were not being specific on how to make the selection... so we are checking for every odd `.row` class and doing different stuff for the `.column1` and `.column2` in order to float them in opposite directions. You will of course have to calculate your margin or padding for this to work, but you get the idea right?